# Alphanumeric password validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written function in javascript for alphanumeric password validation in jsp and calling that function on onkeypress event of textbox but not working.

```js
function alphanumeric(inputtxt) {
  var mypswd = document.getElementById(inputtxt).value;
  mypswd = mypswd.trim();
  if (mypswd == "" || mypswd == null) {
    alert("Please enter password");
  } else if (!mypswd.match((/^(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)) {
    alert(" password must be alphanumeric");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Register">Username :
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="uname" onkeypress="return checkSpcialChar(event)" onkeydown=" alphanumeric(inputtxt)" />
  <br/>Password :
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" onkeypress="return checkSpcialChar(event)" />
  <br/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" onsubmit="check()" />
  <input type="submit" value="Back" />
</form>
```

please help.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a little as some of it was not required for the final outcome you wanted.

The main points are.

```
onkeyup="alphanumeric(this)"
```

You can pass in the element that the event was bound to using `this`. Also I changed the event to `onkeyup` so you can validate the currently typed character.

When you are getting the value you can then use that element to get the current value.

```
var mypswd = input.value.trim()
```

Alerts are really annoying and they block any further execution of the script or interaction with the page, so I put in a div that contains a message so the user get's live feedback of the status of their password.

If you just want alfanumeric validation you can greatly simplify your regular expression to `/[^a-z0-9]+/i` it's simply checking for any non alfanumeric characters.

```js
const message = document.querySelector('.message')

function alphanumeric(input) {
  var mypswd = input.value.trim()
  if (mypswd == "" || mypswd == null) {
    message.innerHTML = "Please enter password"
  } else if (mypswd.match(/[^a-z0-9]+/i)) {
    message.innerHTML = "password must be alphanumeric"
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = "All good in the hood"
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Register">
  <div class="message">Please enter a password</div>
  Passsword :
  <input type="text" 
    name="pword"
    id="pword"
    onkeyup=" alphanumeric(this)" 
  />
</form>
```